# Typo in the title attribute of introduction topic

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-topics

There is a typo in the title attribute of "Introduction Topic" in the `h1` of Getting Started documentation topics ([example topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/193/getting-started-with-python-language)).

`Ths topic is an introduction to` should be `This topic is an introduction to`.

[image]

Comment: @tuna you needed a red free hand circle?

Comment: @rene Yeah. I didn't see it at first.

Comment: you and your fish-eye ... ;)

Comment: This could be corrected by a simple edit... oh wait, not even close to 6 characters. Sincere question - once I gain enough to make a code formatting edit that is 4 characters because someone forgot to indent a first line of code, will I be able to do it?

Comment: @dfd It's not a problem in the community submitted code, it's the website code itself. Basically every introduction topic on the site has the same mistake - only the devs can fix it.

Comment: Looks like we didn't have enough `i`s, er, eyes on that copy.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report! Ths will be fixed in the next prod build.